# No subdomain in link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In the following link hast to be the subdomain included but it isn't. Can anyone explain me how to to that?

```
<%= link_to(t('email.edit_cancel_link'),edit_sub_url(key: @subscriber.ticketcode))%>
```

this returns
    http://something.com/edit_sub?key=4sC3pnRIi5OP3I8wVwnhLw
and not 
    http://subdomain.something.com/edit_sub?key=4sC3pnRIi5OP3I8wVwnhLw

Thanks David

Answer (score 0):

By default, it should return url with `subdomain`.
Yes, there is a option named `subdomain` in url helper.

> Did you tried `<%= link_to(t('email.edit_cancel_link'), edit_sub_url(key: @subscriber.ticketcode, subdomain: true))%>`?

Found an [issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2025) in `rails` repo.

Comment: how did you configured your `subdomain` of your application?